# How to replace RocksDB by in-memory db just for integration tests?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, rocksdb

Since RocksDB still doesn't support Apple Silicon currently only x86_64 JDKs via Rosetta can be used which are 5 times slower than a native JDK.
Therefore I'd like to replace RocksDB by an in-memory key-value store.
How can Kafka be configured to use such an in-memory store by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's similar to jego's answer, but I work with suppliers.
This is how I configured them:

```kotlin
@Profile("prod || stage || test")
@Configuration
class PersistentStoreConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun projektanhangStoreSupplier(): KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(ProjektanhangStore.NAME)
}

@Profile( "it || dev")
@Configuration
class ProjektInMemoryStoreConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun projektanhangStoreSupplier(): KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(ProjektanhangStore.NAME)
}
```

And this is where and how the supplier selected according to the spring profile will be injected and used. Pay attention to the @Bean and @Configuration class names.

```kotlin
@Configuration
class ProjektAnhangStreamConfiguration {
    @Inject
    private lateinit var projektanhangStoreSupplier: KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier

    @Bean
    fun projektanhaenge() = Consumer<KStream<String, AnhangEvent>> {
        it.map { _, v -> KeyValue(v.anhang.projektId, v) }
            .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.StringSerde(), JsonSerde(AnhangEvent::class.java)))
            .aggregate(
                { ProjektanhangAggregator() },
                { _, anhangEvent, aggregator ->
                    when (anhangEvent.action) {
                        CREATE -> aggregator.add(anhangEvent.anhang)
                        DELETE -> aggregator.remove(anhangEvent.anhang)
                        UPDATE -> aggregator.update(anhangEvent.anhang)
                    }
                },
                Materialized
                    .`as`<String, ProjektanhangAggregator>(projektanhangStoreSupplier)
                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                    .withValueSerde(JsonSerde(ProjektanhangAggregator::class.java))
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding `storeBuilder` to `StreamsBuilder`, you can choose to build a persistent (rocksdb) or in-mem store.

```
    final var storeBuilder = Stores.windowStoreBuilder(
//        Stores.persistentWindowStore(storeName, Duration.ofMinutes(10), Duration.ofMinutes(1),
//            false),
        Stores.inMemoryWindowStore(storeName, Duration.ofMinutes(10), Duration.ofMinutes(1),
            false),
        Serdes.String(),
        Serdes.String()
    );
    builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder);
```

Make sure to override the `storeBuilder` on your test-case.